# I want display 5 Charts Vertically in RDLC (SSRS)

Tags: charts, reporting-services, rdlc

I want to display the 5 charts in a row vertically. I was able to add the 3 chart area vertically but after adding the 4th and 5th Chart area it will split into 2 column.

[Example Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sARN.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is not enough information in your question. You need to share your current design etc. 
Please read the following https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.